# Dúvida sobre a criação de um objecto

Tags: javascript

Sou nova nesse mundo da programação em Javascript e ainda tenho imensas dificuldades com coisas que são, a meu ver, relativamente simples mas que ainda não consegui resolver. Eu pretendo criar uma função que mostre vários objetos em um canvas HTML5 dentro do animate CC. Tenho vários .png na minha biblioteca com nomes tipo: a1, a2, a3..., a13, b1, b2... etc. Escolho aleatoriamente 3 ou 4 desses objectos para mostrar no canvas. Entretanto não sei como fazer a ligação entre o nome da variável que passo para a minha função e o objecto a criar no canvas.

A variável **desenho** passada como parâmetro é uma string com o nome dos objectos a1, a2, etc. Mas ao criar a nova variável cards não posso colocar o nome da variável onde tenho em itálico. Ali ele aceita o nome dos objectos directamente mas não sei como ligar a uma variável que passo como parâmetro.

```
function Desenhar(**desenho**) {
   var cards = new lib.*desenho*();
   this.addChild(cards);
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar-me?

Como? :) São várias funções, algumas ainda não terminei, principalmente as de desenho. O código é uma implementação do jogo BlackJack. Tenho botões para fazer as chamadas das funções principais. Aparentemente o jogo em si funciona. Distribui as cartas, verifica os valores, faz a somas e diz quem ganhou, perdeu ou foi eliminado. Tenho uma interface simples feita no animate com os botões. Agora queria desenhar o jogo a medida que acontece. Posso ter erros no código e de certeza os tenho mas agora bati no problema do desenho. Se fosse um objeto só eu poderia arrastar para o canvas e mostrar quando quisesse, mas as cartas são escolhidas de forma aleatória e são muitas cartas. A cardVal passada como parâmetro assumo sempre os nomes das cartas, a1, a2, etc...

Answer (score 2):

É possível acessar propriedades e métodos por nome (como string) usando colchetes em vez do ponto. Você pode fazer assim:

```
function Desenhar(tipoDesenho) {
   var cards = new lib[tipoDesenho]();
   this.addChild(cards);
}
```

Comment: Foi apenas uma pequena alteração...                                            
                                                                                                       
`function showCard(cardVal, whichHand) {        
// nova carta
 
 var newCard = Array();
 
 if (newCard!="") {
  newCard=null;
 }
 
 eval("newCard = new lib."+cardVal+"()");
 self.addChild(newCard);
 newCard.push = cardVal;`